# list-style-type and display:inline-block question

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

So ultimately I want the items under my "page navigation" to span across my screen in an inline format without any bullets, but for some reason I'm having issues with this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me figure out what's going on, thanks.

Comment: Please post the code in actual code snippets and not images, it makes it extremely uncomfortable to help you out like this.

Comment: Also: what do you mean by inline? do you want each item in the list to stack up in the same line? That seems odd. Don't you want it to remain in a sidebar vertical status? Or is it supposed to be a horizontal navbar?

Comment: Post your code in 4 space indent or inline code style with backtick "`". putting screenshot never helps you in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

For the bullet-points it's `list-style` not `list-style-type` that needs to be set to `none`

For the horizontal line, first set up `<ul>` to `display: flex;` so it will go across the horizontal screen. Then let the `<li>` elements be `display: inline-block` in that space.

Here's a jsfiddle with those changes and a few extra ones to make it look better:
https://jsfiddle.net/p9mL2tnd/1/

And here's the code:

**html:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <h3>Page Navigation</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
     <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
a:link {
  color: #fff;
}

a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

a:active {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fc0;
  background-color: #006a9d;
}

a:focus {
  color: #fc0;
}

div#nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

h3 {
  background-color: beige;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #0080c0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

Comment: well the thing is I have other ul, ol, li items on my page so I didn't want to do something like this...  li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #0080c0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}    if I could I wanted to do ul li a{  }

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:link { color: #fff;}
a:visited { color: #fff;}
a:hover { color: #fff;}
a:active { color: #fc0; background: 006a9d;}
a:focus { color: #fc0;}
#nav h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
    color: #71e62a;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #48e0e6;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0080c0;
}
ul li a {
   background-color: #0080c0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial,"sans serif";
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <h3>page navigation</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook Page</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: well the thing is I have other ul, ol, li items on my page so I didn't want to do something like this...  li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #0080c0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}    if I could I wanted to do ul li a{  }